# MPI Autocompletion in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, mpi

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code to develop Fortran MPI programs. However, while I can successfully build and run them just fine, it would be very helpful for me if I can use intellisense/autocompletion features for MPI (as well as other external modules). I have `/usr/lib/openmpi/` (which contains `mpi_f08.mod`) as part of `fortran.includePaths` in my `settings.json`. However, when I `use mpi_f08`, I get the problem message from VS Code `Module "mpi_f08" not found in project`. Here is a minimal CMake build example:

```
! hello.f90
program hello
    use mpi_f08
    implicit none

    integer :: ierror, nproc, my_rank

    call MPI_Init()
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierror)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_rank, ierror)

    print*, "hello from rank ", my_rank

    call MPI_Finalize()

end program hello
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(hello_mpi)
enable_language(Fortran)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)

add_executable(hello_mpi hello.f90)
include_directories(${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH})
target_link_libraries(hello_mpi PUBLIC ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
```

I would like to be able to (i) get rid of the warning/message and more importantly (ii) enable suggestions from MPI when I press CTRL+space as it would if I was calling from an internal module.

Comment: This is Intel oneAPI?

Comment: I am using gfortran (and the "Modern Fortran" extension in VSCode, though I don't mind using another).

Answer (score 3):

I'll post a partial answer since it's better than nothing, hopefully this helps someone else and/or enables someone else to answer my question fully.

It seems the issue relates to the Fortran language server, which can be configured by adding a `.fortls` JSON file, as explained on its Github README: https://github.com/hansec/fortran-language-server

I added the following, which allowed it to find not only local modules but also MPI (and the external module `json-fortran`):

```
{
  "source_dirs": ["src", "."],
  "ext_source_dirs": [
      "/path/to/json-fortran/src", 
    "/path/to/openmpi-4.1.2/ompi/mpi/fortran/use-mpi-f08",
]
}
```

This doesn't capture all functions in `json-fortran`, which I think is because of its `.inc` files, as it doesn't give me function pointers like `json_file::get` at autocomplete.

As for MPI, this kind of works, as it gives me all the functions I can think of needing, but with `_f08` appended to the end of it. I don't know the inner workings of OpenMPI but I guess e.g. `MPI_Init` wraps `MPI_Init_f08` for reasons of backward compatibility. For now I can simply autocomplete to the `_f08` version and remove that bit manually. (I also tried adding `openmpi-4.1.2/ompi/mpi/fortran/use-mpi-tkr` and `openmpi-4.1.2/ompi/mpi/fortran/mpif.h` but no luck).

Would be nice to get this detail sorted though. It is also mildly annoying that I must manually include the source dirs now (removing it makes it not find local modules).

Comment: Where are you putting this file - just in your root directory of the project?

Comment: @abinitio Sorry, I haven't developed in MPI for a while now, but if I recall, yes this was just in the root directory.